# Что обозначает символ собачки в URL адресе?

Tags: url, php, javascript

Добрый день.

Интересует такой вопрос. Подгрузить данные аяксом, чтоб не перезапускать страницу и быстрее работать, но при этом как-то сохранить это действие, чтобы потом к нему можно было бы быстро вернуться. Зашёл на карты гугла, где есть url адрес, потом стоит знак @, после чего идут координаты. URL меняется, но фактически вся страница при этом не перезагружется, и в случае чего можно скопировать ссылку и вернуться к нужному месту.

Собственно вопрос: что обозначает символ url - @  и #? Как их присвоить строке и как потом сосчитать?

Спасибо.

Comment: Используется технология History API и что в данном случае обозначают символы - это уже вопрос вторичный, т.к. та же решетка (**#**) уже может служить не как хэш, в привычном использовании, а как 
какая-нибудь метка или разделитель, которые помогут в дальнейшем разобрать строку запроса и получить набор необходимых данных.

Comment: @Роман Ракзин

1. HTML5 наконец-то предоставило возможность изменять адресную строку без фактического перехода пользователя по новому адресу. Таким образом, в адресной строке может быть что угодно.
2. Хэш (все, что идет после решетки #) вообще не относится к адресу в традиционном понимании (не передается на сервер и изначально осуществлял навигацию на клиенте), поэтому его можно менять из js, и поэтому до HTML5 его использовали как альтернативный адрес, используемый js.

Answer (score 2):

**Структура URL:**

Изначально локатор URL был разработан как система для максимально естественного указания на местонахождения ресурсов в сети. Локатор должен был быть легко расширяемым и использовать лишь ограниченный набор ASCII‐символов (к примеру, пробел никогда не применяется в URL). В связи с этим, возникла следующая традиционная форма записи URL:

*<схема>://<логин>:<пароль>@<хост>:<порт>/?<параметры>#<якорь>*

***схема*** 
схема обращения к ресурсу; в большинстве случаев имеется в виду сетевой протокол

***логин*** 
имя пользователя, используемое для доступа к ресурсу

**пароль** 
пароль указанного пользователя

***хост*** 
полностью прописанное доменное имя хоста в системе DNS или IP-адрес хоста в форме четырёх групп десятичных чисел, разделённых точками; числа — целые в интервале от 0 до 255.

***порт*** 
порт хоста для подключения

***URL-путь*** 
уточняющая информация о месте нахождения ресурса; зависит от протокола.

***параметры*** 
строка запроса с передаваемыми на сервер (методом GET) параметрами. Начинается с символа ?, разделитель параметров — знак &. Пример: ?параметр_1=значение_1&параметр_2=значение_2&параметр3=значение_3

***якорь*** 
идентификатор с предшествующим символом #. Якорем может быть указан заголовок внутри документа или атрибут id элемента. По такой ссылке браузер откроет страницу и переместит окно к указанному элементу.